# Getting Tomcat 7 to work on remote CentOS 7.5

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, centos, remote-access, remote-desktop

I am trying to run a website (WAR-file)on a remote CentOS 7.5 VM. 
I have access to this VM through ssh connection with putty and am able to remote view desktop. The current problem is that even though Tomcat can start, when trying to wget or via browser to view the website a "Connection refused" is returned. I have checked that I request from the right ports and Tomcat does not throw an exception on startup that no port could be opened.

Answer (score 0):

Has it something to do with firewall, which might be preventing access to the port.

Or you might want to map the exposed tomcat port to an external port.

Comment: I am sorry if this was not clear, but I cannot reach tomcat through the VM locally as well as my own workstation.